# How to configure special keys?

Tags: shortcut-keys, dell, inspiron, keyboard-accelerators

This is not as common as it sounds, please check this picture.[image]

There are 3 buttons on the top right. The one on the left has "gears" on it, the one in the middle has "W" like shape and the one on the right has something like a window with a star on it's bottom-left side.

Is there a way to configure these buttons ? I tried many tools like `showkey`, `xmodmap` and others, but none could capture the signal of any of those 3 keys. Is there a way to configure them ?

Comment: Try `xev -event keyboard` and then press those keys. Does it capture anything?

Comment: I was able to get the left one to work by assigning a keybing to win+x, which is the combination that showkey and showkey -s showed when pressing that key. showkey must be run from a login terminal with ctrl+alt+F(2-6). None of the other two keys showed any scancodes or keycodes here though.